# Is JSON (still) a valid JavaScript code aka. moving objects from backend to frontend

Tags: javascript, json, frontend, backend

A rather theoretical question:
Let's say we have some object in the backend (let's ignore what technology and language it is) and we want to move (or actually copy) it into JavaScript code on the frontend side during rendering the page.

The reason why I'm asking about JSON is that many backends have some kind of json-ify function that takes an object in this language and produces JSON string out of it. It's tempting to use that in this way:

```
<script>
var myObject = ( <%= backendObject.to_json() %> );
// ...
</script>
```

but I'm not sure if this will work for all cases. For one, I know that objects in JS are written like this:

```
{
   x: 10,
   y: 20
}
```

and in JSON like this:

```
{
   "x": 10,
   "y": 20
}
```

but I'm sure about this either. On the other side JSON acronym is expanded to "**JavaScript** Object Notation", so it should have some common ground with JS. However I don't know if it *still* has.

**PS:** I know it may be simpler to render a page with JS code that `fetch()`-es the object from the backend, which json-ifes it. But it will be two HTTP requests. Besides sometimes you have got the object right now when the first request is made.

Comment: JSON syntax is a subset of JavaScript object initializer syntax. Any valid JSON string works perfectly well as a JavaScript object initializer. So yes, it does work for all cases.

Comment: For example: in JS the quotes are optional for object parameter names that are valid identifiers, and can be either single or double. For JSON they're not optional for any names, and must always be double. JSON is valid JS, although the reverse isn't true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), it is a subset of a version of JavaScript (ECMA-262 3rd Edition). So I guess the answer is "yes".

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format. It is easy for humans to read and write. It is easy for machines to parse and generate. It is based on a subset of the JavaScript Programming Language Standard ECMA-262 3rd Edition - December 1999.

Edit: upon [further reading](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset) it seems that there may be one technicality relating to new line characters `U+2028` and `U+2029` that JSON can have inside strings, but JavaScript can't. However, you can escape them as `\u2028` and `\u2029`.

Comment: Those are little 'but'-s I was afraid of.